# Features that should be pushed a bit more

Tags: discussion, user-interface

I just now discovered that if you click on the actual vote total of a question (between the up/down arrows) it gives a breakdown of the total vote amounts in each direction.  I had no clue this was possible, and was considering suggesting something like it or trying to find a chrome extension to add this functionality (like with RES).

Are there any other hidden gems that people know about to make using this site a bit more...if not easier, at least a bit more in-depth?  If we can come up with some that aren't very well known, perhaps we could add a few lines/a section to the FAQ detailing them, for new readers.

Comment: there is a large collection at MSO: **[Hidden features of Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8211/165773)**

Comment: Additionally, be sure to check out [StackApps](http://stackapps.com), which is the site for those who build Userscripts and browser extensions that enhance Stack Exchange using the Stack Exchange API. There are all sorts of features the community has added that aren't part of the core of Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is one of the [privileges](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/privileges) earned by gaining reputation. Most, if not all, of these features are described on the privileges page, along with indicators of your progress towards them (place your mouse over the percentage to see the reputation threshold to unlock it).

An additional slightly non-obvious feature is advanced search options. Visit the [search page](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search) and click "Advanced search tips" on the right for some useful filtering options.

There are also @ replies in comments. You can reply to another user in a comment, and that user will be notified. This is done by sticking an "@" before their name. This (usually) offers autocomplete. You can reply to only one user in your comment, and you can only reply to a user who has commented on or edited that same post. The post author is always notified of new comments.

You may also be interested in [Hidden features of Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8211/167443) (covers a lot of Stack Exchange network-wide features), as well as [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445/167443), which is a list of all new/recently changed features on the network. While not "hidden", some of these may not be well-known.

Comment: o.O  i never knew that priveleges page existed.  I was going mostly off of what was in the FAQ regarding reputation.  I see now that the thing I was talking about comes from being an established user".  Still, it feels like there could be a better way of notifying users of abilities and things they unlock, as they unlock them.

Comment: You can get to the priveleges page by hovering over the triangle at the top of the page next to your name, then clicking "priveleges". Some of them do notify you. There are certain factors that affect that, though. I'll see if I can find details.

Comment: Might be out date, but this describes approximately whether or not you will get notified: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/84317/167443

Comment: Ok, thanks for this.